# Migrating db with rails gem apartment and multi-tenant returns PG::InvalidSchemaName

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apartment-gem

I run rake db:migrate and I get the following error:

```
PG::InvalidSchemaName: ERROR:  no schema has been selected to create in
LINE 1: CREATE TABLE "schema_migrations" ("version" character varyin..
```

This is on Rails 6, with gem 'ros-apartment'.

Application is running smoothly if tenant is accesing public schema.
Iḿ forcing apartment to create SQL dumps as I need some specific postgre stuff

```
config.use_sql = true
```

What should I check? I'm not getting any results changing "schema_search_path" or "config.default_schema"

Thanks!

Comment: Hi Joserra, mind opening a ticket in the repository of the gem? we can move the discussion to there and avoid the noise on Stack Overflow. This might be a bug on the gem

Comment: Thanks @rpbaltazar but problem disappeared. To be honest i don't know the reason, but after cleaning database and updating dependencies now it's ok.